# asp listbox set different label for values

Tags: asp.net

here's how I populate my listbox

```
ImageList.Items.Clear();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FileImageFolder, "*" + SearchTerms.Text.Replace(" ", "*") + "*");
        files = Array.FindAll(files, delegate(string f) { return IsImage(f); });

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (IsImage(file))
                ImageList.Items.Add(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        }
```

it will display file name of images (together with its folder n path) on the list box. however what if I want to display other text instead of the file name (and its path) of the images on the listbox? for example maybe image1, image2 instead of images/bbla/image_1.jpg and images/bbla/cat.jpg. but I don't want to change the attached value.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple

```
int id=1;
foreach (string file in files)
{
    if (IsImage(file))
        ImageList.Items.Add(new ListItem("image"+id++,file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)));
}
```

or you can do it as follow

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    if (IsImage(file))
    {
       ListItem li=new ListItem("image"+id++,file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('/') + 1))
       ImageList.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

or you can use `Array.Length` and use `for loop` instead of `foreach loop`.